# Integrate SSRS report to have eSignature capacity through DocuSign

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, docusignapi

is it possible to integrate the SSRS reports I have to incorporate eSignature capacity using DocuSign? Or do I need to revamp the report set I have and re-do them in DocuSign? These reports are attached to emails and sent to customers for manual signatures currently. Trying to improve this process. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It depends in what format the report is generated and also how you want to place DocuSign Signature tabs on the report document. I do not think there is out of the box DocuSign plugin or connector with SSRS reports, you might need to do some coding to make it DocuSign ready

Comment: are you looking to building an integration using DocuSign API? do you already have one?

Comment: Amit, the ssrs reports have rdl extensions.I was hoping there's some kind of plugin so i can keep the reports i have... i don't mind doing some coding to make it DocuSign ready either if it isn't complicated. Are there some sample codes you aware of?

Comment: Inbar, I am looking at building an integration using DocuSign API. Now building an integration using DocuSign will require me to use a DocuSign template to generate my reports right?

Comment: How do I get rid of this error? I am doing what this tutorial is suggesting to do (https://youtu.be/ADmELHcPpbM) ApiException: Error calling CreateEnvelope: { "errorCode": "AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_TOKEN", "message": "The access token provided is expired, revoked or malformed." }

Answer (score 0):

You can use the output of SSRS report as either HTML, PDF or raw text to create an envelop and build an integration using the DocuSign eSinature API and you will be using OAuth for authentication. Your token issue will be addressed on your newest question you posted - [AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_TOKEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59995056/authorization-invalid-token)

Comment: do i need to add signature fields to the SSRS report? I wonder if there's a tutorial that explains how to do what you suggested. Basically, I have 3 spots in an SSRS report that I want electronic signatures on. The report is dynamic and it gets much of its values from SQL data sources. How do I make this scenario possible? Glad to know there is a way though. N.B. The token issue is fixed now.

Comment: yes, please follow the steps in this code example - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-embedded-signing

Comment: Thank you for the code example. I will check it out.