# AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_TOKEN

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, token, docusignapi

How do I get rid of this error? I am following the steps mentioned in the DocuSign tutorial https://youtu.be/ADmELHcPpbM

```
ApiException: Error calling CreateEnvelope: { "errorCode": "AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_TOKEN", 
"message": "The access token provided is expired, revoked or malformed." }
```

And to be clear, the TOKEN isn't expired and still has 7 hours left on it.

Comment: how did you obtain the token? what are you trying to do with the token? can you share your code?

Comment: Did this token ever work, or did it suddenly start failing? Are you including `bearer` in your authorization header in front of the token itself?

Comment: Use "copy to clipboard" button instead of copy and paste. I will allow to copy all key without truncation.

Comment: I got the token from this page: https://developers.docusign.com/oauth-token-generator. It never worked and yes I used the “copy to clipboard” button. I got the code from quick start up samples by DocuSign at this link: https://github.com/docusign/qs-02-node-send-envelope. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you didn't copy the entire access token from the DocuSign Access Token generator.

Perhaps a better path for you is to switch to the C# .Net Core example launcher which includes over 20 workflow examples. See https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core